# Nexus 6P can't be kept charging

Tags: nexus-6p

When I charge my Nexus 6P, the charging often stops (probably after the battery level becomes 100% once.) and it keep consuming power.

As a result, when I unplug the cable, it has often low battery or already shut down although I expect it is fully charged.

Is it well known issue?

Comment: Never seen anything like that on my own 6P. More like a phone-side issue, but try switching chargers anyway.

Comment: No. Never heard anything like that before. You might want to replace the phone and/or the charger. Are you using the original charger? Try using a different charge if you have access to one. (Any charger with an Type-A out would work in conjunction with the included Type-A to Type-C cable)

Comment: Thanks. I use 1) adaptor from outlet to 2 USB port, 2) USB Type-A Extension Cable, and 3) USB Type A to Type C cable. I have replaced 3) and will keep watching what will happen. Seems like it didn't happen last night though.

Comment: Restart your phone. I had the same problem, but looks like its some glitch on software that manages the charging functions